# Spring beans based on properties

Tags: java, spring

I am wondering if the below is possible in Spring

1. Read a property file using spring - this file has a list of jms queue names
2. Make spring loop on the above list and define beans that define Apache camel routes from that queue to a file

I could just create the routes using java code on the apache camel context, but wondering if it is possible through spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a property file in a Spring XML wiring file is easy; e.g. using a [`PropertiesFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html).  However, the second part of the problem cannot (I believe) be solved without writing a significant amount of Java code.

I suggest that you read [Section 3.8.3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) of the Spring Reference that describes how to write your own FactoryBean classes.  Another possibility is to create a custom Java configuration bean as described in [Section 3.11](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java).  There may be other possibilities too.

Warning: none of this stuff is particularly straight-forward if you are coming at it for the first time.

Comment: Thanks - I think I could use the factory bean and Camel RouteBuilder to build the routes and inject into the camel context. Will give it a shot.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by creating a factory bean that returned an instance of the route builder for camel. The properties read by the property factory bean are passed to the factory bean.